# Как перенести на хостинг сайт,  сделанный на Java, с помощью Spring?

Tags: java, hosting, сервер

Практикую Spring. Использую ceрвер GlassFish. На данном этапе удалось создать несколько страниц веб. Но хотел бы их увидеть не на localhost, а на удаленном сервере(в моем понимании, перенести на хостинг, если правильно высказываюсь.)

Comment: Так а что вам мешает так же поднять сервер на удалённом хосте и задеплоить приложение в него?

Comment: вот имею об этом смутное предложение, может есть какая то литература, как это можно сделать.? просто хостил раньше только простые сайты. процедура там простая. будет ли на java все делаться в такой же способ?

Comment: > вот имею об этом смутное предложение
Но вы же как-то локальный GlassFish настроили и используете?
> может есть какая то литература, как это можно сделать
Конечно, загляните в документацию по Tomcat/Jetty/etc, из неё и узнаете, как установить, сконфигурировать сервер и задеплоить в него приложение.
> процедура там простая
Да и тут, в общем-то, не сложнее.

Comment: Вообще, вы лучше почитайте, попробуйте, и если возникнут какие-то определённые затруднения, конкретно по ним и задавайте вопросы. Сейчас же ваш вопрос слишком общий, и иного способа полноценно ответить на него, кроме как цитировать документацию, я не вижу.

Comment: ок, буду копать